# call sqlite database path on mobile (ios android) cross platform QT

Tags: android, ios, database, qt, sqlite

I'm making an app to `ios` and `android`.
I need to get custom database, I created a `sqlite` database with DB browser for `sqlite` client.
I called `db.sqlite` and I put them (database folder) in the solution of my `qt` creator:

[image]

So, I created a db manager class, you see in the functions folder.
But I don't know how to call the db path.
This is my dbmanager class code:

```
DbManager::DbManager(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    m_db.setDatabaseName(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath().append("/database/db.sqlite"));
    bool connected = m_db.open();

    if (!connected) {
        qDebug() << "Error: connection with database failed";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Database: connection success";

        QSqlQuery q(m_db);

        q.prepare("SELECT * FROM oven");

        if (q.exec()) {
            qDebug() << "Yay!";
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Bad exec: " << q.lastError();
            qDebug() << q.executedQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tryed change some folders path, for example:
:database/db.sqlite
or
:../database/db.sqlite
or
db.sqlite only

Everey this solutions don't work, I need an help. 
What is the correct path to call my custom database ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use realmdb if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use random paths on mobile. Try something like this:

`m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
QString dbLocation = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation);
m_db.setDatabaseName(dbLocation + "/" + m_dbname);`

Where m_dbname ist the name of your Database.

Comment: Where do I put the database file ? You solution return me two differents path, ios and android return path it's not equal path....so where do i put the database file ?wich folder?

Comment: Of course it shows you two different paths. That's the whole point! Every platform has its own standard locations but they are differnent on every platform. Using the above will give you the platform-specific path. In other words: put it into the directory which QStandardPaths will give you. The code is the same on all platforms but the locations will be obviously different. Look here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html